# C# EF Core 7 Migration | custom action (create triggers and tables)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I've implemented a solution to audit some tables with the fewest code as possibele.

An example table/entity:

```
public class Vehicle : BaseEntity, IAudit
{
    public string Plate { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Make { get; set; } = default!;
    //...
    public Audit Audit { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

The Audit class and IAudit interface:

```
public class Audit
{
    public User? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public AuditType Type { get; set; } = AuditType.Update;
}
public interface IAudit
{
    Audit Audit { get; set; }
}
```

My dbContext OnModelCreating contains the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(x => x.Id).IsClustered(false);

    e.Property(x => x.Plate).HasMaxLength(10);
    e.Property(x => x.Make).HasMaxLength(255);
    //...
    e.HasAuditTrigger();
});
```

The HasAuditTrigger extension method fill Annotations of entitybuilder:

```
    public static class EntitTypeBuilderExtensions
    {
        private static void AuditBuilder<Owner>(OwnedNavigationBuilder<Owner, Audit> audit) where Owner : BaseEntity, IAudit
        {
            audit.Property(x => x.Type)
                .HasColumnType("nchar(1)")
                .HasConversion<string>(t => ((char)(int)t).ToString(), t => (AuditType)t[0]);
        }

        public static EntityTypeBuilder HasAuditTrigger<T>(this EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder, bool phisicalDelete = true) where T : BaseEntity, IAudit
        {
            builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Audit, AuditBuilder);

            var entityName = typeof(T).Name;
            var tableName = builder.Metadata.GetTableName();
            var auditTableName = entityName + "Audit";
            var mainColumns = builder.Metadata.GetProperties()
                //.Where(p => p.Name != "Id")
                .Select(p => $"[{p.Name}]");
            var ownedColumns = builder.Metadata.GetNavigations()
                .Where(n => n.ForeignKey.IsOwnership)
                .SelectMany(n => n.ForeignKey.DeclaringEntityType.GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.FieldInfo != null)
                    .Select(p => new { nav = n.Name, prop = p.Name }))
                .Select(p => $"[{p.nav}_{p.prop}]");
            var allColumns = String.Join(", ", mainColumns.Union(ownedColumns));

            var sql = @$"
SELECT * INTO {auditTableName}
FROM {tableName}
WHERE 1 = 0
";

            builder.Metadata.AddAnnotation("AuditTable", sql);

            sql = @$"
CREATE TRIGGER {tableName}_AuditTigger
   ON {tableName}
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO {auditTableName} ({allColumns})
    SELECT {allColumns} FROM inserted
" + (phisicalDelete
? @$"
    DELETE FROM {tableName}
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM inserted WHERE Audit_Type = 'D')"
: "") + @"
END
";
            builder.Metadata.AddAnnotation("AuditTrigger", sql);

            builder.ToTable(t => t.HasTrigger($"{tableName}_AuditTigger"));

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

In startup:

```
if (ctx.Database.EnsureCreated())
{
    ctx.CreateAuditTriggers();
}
```

It calls a method in the dbContext:

```
        public void CreateAuditTriggers()
        {

            var auditTableAnnotations = this.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(et => et.GetAnnotations()).Where(a => a.Name == "AuditTable").ToList();
            if (auditTableAnnotations != null)
            {
                foreach(var annotation in auditTableAnnotations)
                    if (annotation.HasValue())
                        this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw((string)annotation.Value!);
            }

            var auditTriggerAnnotations = this.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(et => et.GetAnnotations()).Where(a => a.Name == "AuditTrigger").ToList();
            if (auditTriggerAnnotations != null)
            {
                foreach(var annotation in auditTriggerAnnotations)
                    if (annotation.HasValue())
                        this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw((string)annotation.Value!);
            }
        }
```

The above concept working well. With small portion of code I can create an audit table and a trigger automatically. The problem is that I have to implement migration but the migration builder know nothing about triggers and tables. I have to remove ctx.Database.EnsureCreated() so I can't create triggers.

I've no idea how can I override snapshoting or code generating to add/maintain audit tables and triggers automatically (based on metadata annotations or anything). I don't want to create audit entites in the code and add it to model builder manually.

I tried implement own entity service (for example IMigrationsCodeGenerator) but my experience is not enought. I'd like to create/modify audit triggers and tables with migration.

Do you have any idea?